# Pulseaudio ignores/overrides my configuration files

Tags: pulseaudio

It seems that pulseaudio is failing to read my configuration files, or something is overriding it with settings from elsewhere.

As an example, I can't disable autospawn:

```
fa2k@blackhole:~$ grep autospawn /etc/pulse/client.conf
autospawn = no
fa2k@blackhole:~$ ls -l /etc/pulse/client.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1198 mai   21 15:01 /etc/pulse/client.conf
fa2k@blackhole:~$ ls -l .config/pulse
total 7
-rw------- 1 fa2k ateam 256 mai   21 15:06 cookie
```

When I run `pulseaudio -k`, it still comes back immediately.

I've tried to copy over files from `/etc/pulse/` into my user's configuration directory, but it doesn't change anything.

The following is output in the journal when I try to kill pulseaudio

```
mai 21 15:06:19 blackhole systemd[3979]: pulseaudio.service: Succeeded.
mai 21 15:06:19 blackhole systemd[3979]: Starting Sound Service...
mai 21 15:06:23 blackhole pulseaudio[400784]: module-combine is deprecated: Please use module-combine-sink instead of module-combine!
mai 21 15:06:23 blackhole pulseaudio[400784]: We will now load module-combine-sink. Please make sure to remove module-combine from your configuration.
mai 21 15:06:23 blackhole pulseaudio[400784]: Failed to open module module-esound-protocol-tcp.so: module-esound-protocol-tcp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
mai 21 15:06:23 blackhole pulseaudio[400784]: Failed to open module "module-esound-protocol-tcp".
mai 21 15:06:23 blackhole pulseaudio[400784]: pa_module_load() failed
mai 21 15:06:23 blackhole systemd[3979]: Started Sound Service.
mai 21 15:06:24 blackhole gsd-media-keys[391890]: Unable to get default sink
mai 21 15:06:24 blackhole gsd-media-keys[391890]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
mai 21 15:06:24 blackhole gnome-shell[391705]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
mai 21 15:06:56 blackhole gnome-shell[391705]: Source ID 18491 was not found when attempting to remove it
mai 21 15:07:27 blackhole gnome-shell[391705]: Source ID 18725 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

The error about `module-combine` seems like something I've tried years ago, to combine some outputs. Now there's nothing about `module-combine` in `/etc/pulse` or `~/.config/pulse`. I've started a search in my entire home dir to look for that string.

Seems to me that some old configuration file is overriding my attempts to set autospawn, and also bringing in a `module-combine` command (that's not a default thing in Ubuntu, right?).

It could have been like this before the upgrade, but I notice now because one of my sound cards is missing from pulse, but not from ALSA -- the one I actually use.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. Autospawn setting is not respected. This is because [systemd is managing pulseaudio](https://superuser.com/questions/1170433/systemd-keeps-respawning-pulseaudio-and-doesnt-allow-me-to-stop-it).
2. Other residual config:

   The `module-combine` is loaded because of a setting added to gconf by the `paprefs` utility (quite some time ago). It's stored under the key `/system/pulseaudio`. It was solved by unchecking the option to create a simultaneous output in paprefs. I tried to remove that entire tree using:

   ```
   gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /system/pulseaudio
   ```

I can't get rid of the `module-esound-protocol-tcp.so` error, but it's probably caused by `paprefs` as well. It only comes for my user.